# Re-charmar função php, porem está retornando null na segunda chamada

Tags: php, javascript

O que está acontecendo tenho  essa função no  pgp que verifica se já existe a url no banco de dados se já existe simplesmente adiciona um numero na frente, para isso  eu  chamo a função até ela achar uma que não existe exemplo
se meu-nome existe ele vai tentar meu-nome1, meu-nome2 e retornar quando der certo, porem o return só está funcionando na primeira vez, já verifique se o valor existe está ok, somente não está retornando.

```
public function checkUrl($nome,$tabela,$coluna,$cont){
    global $mysql,$fottic; // vairaveis globais
    if($cont > 0){ // veirifca se a função foi chamada novamente
        $url = $nome."-".$cont; // adiciona um numero na url
    }else{ se tiver sido chamada pela prmeiravez normaliza a url
        $url = $fottic->NormalizaURL($nome);
    }
    $qr = mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE $coluna='$url'") or die(mysql_error()); // verifica no db se existe
    if(mysqli_num_rows($qr) == '0'){
        return $url; // se não existe retorna o valor

    }else{
        $cont++;
        $fottic->checkUrl($url,$tabela,$coluna,$cont);
        //se já existe, faz toda função novamente
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui achar o que deu de errado, tinha que retornar a função novamente

```
}else{
    $cont++;
    return  $fottic->checkUrl($url,$tabela,$coluna,$cont);
    //se já existe, faz toda função novamente
}
```